# How can I sort Perl hashes whose values are array references?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, reference, perl-data-structures

Hey I was just wondering if there is a cool "one liner" that would sort my hash holding array references. So I have a bunch of key/values in my hash something like:

```
$DataBase{$key} = \@value;
```

However I would like to sort the hash by the `array[0]` element. Then loop through 'em. I had this to begin with:

```
foreach my $key (sort {$DataBase{$a} cmp $DataBase{$b} } keys %DataBase)
```

But that obviously just sorts my hash by the pointer value of the array. It doesn't exactly have to be "one line" but I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve reconstructing the hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach my $key (sort {$DataBase{$a}->[0] cmp $DataBase{$b}->[0] } keys %DataBase)
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the newbish question... Just started with perl and didn't know i could use the -> operator!

Comment: Should work without the indirections, too, I just like them there because I'm a pedant.

Comment: @Balk: Ah, yeah, it's the 'nice' way of accessing references (as opposed to like @{$value}).

Comment: The -> is optional between two {}/[] things.  See http://perlmonks.org/?node=references+quick+reference

Answer (score 2):

For the record (you probably come from a C background), Perl does not have pointers, but [references](http://oreilly.com/catalog/advperl/excerpt/ch01.html):

> Perl [...] allows you to create
>   anonymous data structures, and
>   supports a fundamental data type
>   called a "reference," loosely
>   equivalent to a C pointer. Just as C
>   pointers can point to data as well as
>   procedures, Perl's references can
>   refer to conventional data types
>   (scalars, arrays, and hashes) and
>   other entities such as subroutines,
>   typeglobs, and filehandles. Unlike C,
>   they don't let you peek and poke at
>   raw memory locations.

Similar, but not the same.

C.

Comment: Another difference is that you can ask a reference what type of thing it refers to with ref or Scalar::Util::reftype.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the same basic question as [How can I sort a hash-of-hashes by key in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743167/how-can-i-sort-a-hash-of-hashes-by-key-in-perl/). My answer, which is in the Perl FAQ, shows you how to sort a hash any way that you like.